# How to request Creative Common content from Youtube with google API

Tags: java, api, youtube

I'm trying to use the Youtube API to grab creative common videos.

I tried to use setField method from YouTubeQuery class but I'm not able to provide the exact string parameter to filter by creative common.

Edit : I'm using Java implementation of the Youtube API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `license` parameter which takes either `cc` or `youtube` as the value, where `cc` means Creative Commons: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#licensesp

I've just tried specifying the parameters directly in the URL and it works:

(cc) - https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer%20&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2&license=cc

(youtube) - https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer%20&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2&license=youtube

If you're using a client library, such as Java, check out this part of the docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Searching_for_Videos

```
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));
query.setFullTextQuery("puppy");    
query.setStringCustomParameter("license", "cc");

VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
```

Comment: I'm using the Java implementation of the Youtube API, I doubt I can append the license parameter.
Sorry for being misleading.

Comment: don't the client api's give you access to the raw url somehow?

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice that you were interested in java. i updated my answer to give you a hint how to set the param using the client lib. i haven't tried it, but it should work according to the docs.

Comment: The YouTubeQuery class has no setLicense method.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Looks like they didn't include methods for everything (which is strange). Looking at the code, you should be using the setStringCustomParameter() method:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/Query.java#850
 I've updated the example.